# Is this a 100% safe from SQL Injection and will work correctly for any input?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

```
$a=$_GET["a"];
$b=$_GET["b"];
$a=str_replace("%", "\%", $a);
$b=str_replace("%", "\%", $b);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table ";
$sql.="WHERE ColA LIKE :txtA AND ColB LIKE :txtB";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':txtA', '%'.$a.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':txtB', '%'.$b.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

I want to give user ability to search anything. Should I filter more characters? Will it be 100% safe and work as it should do for searching pieces of text in database?

Edit:
ColA and ColB are strings, just text (phrase and tags in search engine)

Comment: Please [edit] to add some description.  What do `ColA` and `ColB` represent?  What's the schema?  What flavour of SQL?  This mostly looks like stub/sample code rather than real code from a project.

Comment: @TobySpeight edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security-wise your code is OK. There is **not a single variable** put inside your query string - so you can tell that it's 100% safe.

Regarding the search quality, like you rightfully noted in the comment, there is also a "_" wildcard character.

Besides, as it is noted in the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), a backslash character must be escaped with *three* slashes as well.

So for the bullet-proof escaping for LIKE you could come up with a function

```
function escapeForLike($str) {
    $str = str_replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\", $str);
    $str = str_replace("%", "\%", $str);
    $str = str_replace("_", "\_", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Using this function and some [improvements that PDO offers](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare), you can make your code like this

```
$a = escapeForLike($_GET["a"]);
$b = escapeForLike($_GET["b"]);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColA LIKE :txtA AND ColB LIKE :txtB";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(['txtA' => "%$a%", 'txtB' => "%$b%"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to give user ability to search anything.

It looks like you've achieved that, however, I'd use `$_POST` to reduce the likelihood that your application will be taken offline by users opening multiple tabs or search engine spiders hitting URLs.

> Will it be 100% safe and work as it should do for searching pieces of text in database?

Looks good for SQL injection.

As to whether it "should do" - have you considered generating the query dynamically to allow for tokenized search on inputs like "foo bar"? (i.e. `ColB LIKE :token1 OR ColB LIKE :token2`)

Comment: I forgot about "_" - if user put that it can change searching a lot, but that should be everything. I wanted use GET to allow users save links to their searches. As we talking about tokens - i am not a good programmer and i have no idea what that is. Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: @Steve143 [Tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) can be as simple as an `explode(' ', $input)`, allowing your users to perform a search on multiple words without requiring that those words appear as an exact phrase.